# How can I get Debug Logs for Apex code in my Managed Package which is invoked via Execute Anonymous on the Subscriber Org?

Tags: apex, managed-package, lma, debug-logs

I have installed a Managed Package and connected it via the LMA. The subscriber org shows up under the Subscribers-Tab. An user on the subscriber org has granted me (as package provider) login access. I can log into the subscriber org.

**All fine so far**

But still I can't get any usable log. Im simplifying my issue for the sake of this example. If the "reason" does not make sense to you, please don't ask "why" I need this at all. It's a bigger picture. To explain all would blow the scope of this question. Assume I just need all logs from managed code which is invoked by execute anonymous on the subscriber org. Period. Also I'm not looking for workarounds, because my understanding of the docs is, that it should work as described below. I want to know what I am doing wrong, not what else I could have done...

In my package I have code such as

```
System.debug(logginglevel.WARN, 'some text');
```

My managed package has the prefix "epx". the code above is in the class "xt" in the function "log". everything is global not public.

```
global class xt {
    global static void log(String message){ 
        System.debug(logginglevel.WARN , message); 
    } 
}
```

I want to see that "some text". Therefore I went (after login via LMA) on the subscriber org to the setup and set a user trace flag on myself with an apex loglevel to WARN.

I want to invoke the code via Execute Anonymous on the subscriber org via

```
 epx.xt.log('123');
```

But I'm getting only

```
40.0 APEX_CODE,WARN;APEX_PROFILING,WARN;CALLOUT,WARN;DB,WARN;SYSTEM,WARN
Execute Anonymous: epx.xt.log('123');
19:44:10.186 (186571682)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0051i000000OJCw|heim@xe372.elastify.eu|Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit|GMT+02:00
19:44:10.186 (186624077)|EXECUTION_STARTED
19:44:10.186 (186635584)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
19:44:10.186 (197050273)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
19:44:10.186 (198123764)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

But it should look like

```
START APEX EXECUTION
40.0 APEX_CODE,WARN;APEX_PROFILING,WARN;CALLOUT,WARN;DB,WARN;SYSTEM,WARN
20:07:26.294 (294745247)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0050Y000001DPSm|heim@xe100.elastify.eu|Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit|GMT+02:00
20:07:26.294 (294786251)|EXECUTION_STARTED
20:07:26.294 (294797532)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
20:07:26.294 (322596175)|USER_DEBUG|[459]|WARN|123
20:07:26.294 (322725058)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
20:07:26.294 (324152760)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

**Note**

The line **USER_DEBUG|[459]|WARN|123** is exactly what I want (and unmanaged code would produce).

Now setting a trace on the class xt of the "epx" namespace makes it a bit better, but still not usable:

```
START APEX EXECUTION
40.0 APEX_CODE,WARN;APEX_PROFILING,WARN;CALLOUT,WARN;DB,WARN;SYSTEM,WARN
19:48:16.217 (217950018)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0051i000000OJCw|heim@xe372.elastify.eu|Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit|GMT+02:00
19:48:16.217 (218000232)|EXECUTION_STARTED
19:48:16.217 (218008004)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
19:48:16.217 (227248124)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|epx
19:48:16.217 (228472125)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|epx
19:48:16.217 (228890734)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|epx
19:48:16.217 (229007596)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|epx
19:48:16.217 (229554806)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|epx
19:48:16.217 (229915053)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
19:48:16.217 (231001697)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

**Question**

How can I get usable debug logs from my function `epx.xt.log()`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have actually **two** Managed Packages installed: one namespace is "ec2" the second  (and important one) is "epx". Now at the time, when I've granted login access, there was only ec2 installed. Later I installed "epx". I was prepared to grant login access for epx, too. But there is no option to do that since both MPs are linked to the same LMA/PBO and the login access seems already granted for epx by the granting for ec2 done before. Is my assumption correct, that the login access is granted per **LMA/PBO** and **not per managed package (=namespace)**? If that is true one granting should allow me access to multiple namespaces and I should get debug logs for my understanding in exactly the way I'm trying to get them... or is the order of granting important or is there someting else hidden to deal with many packages per PBO on one subscriber org?

Comment: Is there possibility to use breakpoints in developer console than looking at debug output, sometimes they provide in more depth information.

Comment: Given what you see in the logs, and ignoring that you say you have done it, I would say that you have not logged in to the subscriber org via your PBO's Subscribers login mechanism as a user who has granted you access. That said, you seem to have done the steps needed, including setting up the user trace on the user who granted you access while logged in as them via subscriber access... I only say this to verify with you that this is, indeed, what you have done.

Comment: @philw yes, I logged in via the LMA app installed on the PBO as described in the documentation... only that it does not work and the logs are crippled in the same manner as when I'm logged in directly in the org. my assumption was, it might be related with the invocation via exec anon. but it should not matter.

Comment: @raul for me the most effective way to see what is going on is still to have a plain and clear output in the log. having filterted to WARN, the log is free of clutter an I see all I need at a glance - only that id does not work as advertised or I'm to stupid to understand that feature. If the was an option to disable the log "protection" totally to expose the full log always to any user on the subscriber org, this would be exactly what I want and need.

Comment: In general, it is true that granting access for one package grants access for all packages from that LMA org. I can't think why code excuted through execute anonymous would be different, but prob worth having subscriber revoke ec2 access & grant epx access instead. Are you getting full logs including details within your namespace if you use your package through the regular UI?

Comment: A couple things. Try removing access then grant it again now that both packages are installed. In the subscribers tab make sure you pick the user with epx identified. Also note that for the last year or two you will never get anything but obfuscated code if the code is running in a batch. The whole thing has been very buggy. Also make sure you use the setup ui to set up the logging on the user who granted access. You may also want to try increasing log levels.

Comment: @eric thanks for your feedback, I will check that out. but why would you increase log levels if the specific log im looking for is explicitly set to WARN? do you think that the logs might reveal backgrounds why they are getting suppressed? My experience with less filtered logs is that they contain pure clutter for my purpose and are a pain in the eyes to look at.

Comment: @UweHeim it was just something to try so you could rule it out